# Service that periodically checks whether python script is running and restarts it if it isn't

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a python program which is supposed to be running nonstop. In case that an error occurs, I want a service that periodically (e.g. every hour) checks whether the program is running and if it is not it restarts it.

I am working on a raspberry pi.

I have tried using bash like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
while [ $n -le 2 ]
do
    PID=$(pidof -s python3);
    if [ -z $PID ]; then
        /usr/bin/python3.5 ~/.../main.py
        exit 0;
    fi
    sleep 1h
done
```

I simply look for python3 because it's the only python3 program that will be running.

However it starts the program in the same terminal window, I want it to run in a different window, because it seems that otherwise the two programs would be interfering?

Comment: Why would the two programs interfere?

Comment: They don't feel disconnected to mewhen run in the same terminal window.

Comment: "I want it to run in a different window" Services generally do not run in *any* terminal *window* – you are likely trying to solve a problem that does not or should not exist. Are you aware of ``cront``/``crontab`` and ``init.d``/``systemd``? Note that a straightforward solution is to *accept* that the python process is a child of the bash script; the bash script should ``wait`` for the python process to end and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is meant to be running permanently (as opposed to a one off task), this isn't the right way to go about it. You should look into installing a proper process control system.

There's a few around, but given that systemd ships with most Linux distros, including Raspberry Pi-specific ones, and that there are instructions [available in the Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md), that would be my first choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&` to run your script in the background:

```
    /usr/bin/python3.5 ~/.../main.py &
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out myself, the programs are not interfering like Be Chiller Too has already mentioned and the code works fine if you remove the `exit 0;` and the `sleep 1h` since it will only continue with the script once the program has been terminated. Also I added some output.

```
n=1
while [ $n -le 2 ]
do
    PID=$(pidof -s python3);
    if [ -z $PID ]; then
        echo "Restarting..."
        /usr/bin/python3.5 ~/.../main.py
    fi
done
```